# Strategy to Implement Linked Processes in Python

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

Hey everyone I have a large scope type question that I'd really appriciate feedback/insight on.

I'm a newish programer and am Developing an 'Engine Development Enviorment' for fun at work. I have a program that makes alot of run files, and I have another program that manages batched/local multiprocessed simulations.

I want them to work seamlessly together, but I only want one instance of the 'BatchMaster' to run locally (from the taskbar). I also do alot of scripting type stuff for exploratory data analysis and would love the ability to launch simulations in a single line of code like the following.

```
import enginemodels
aetd = enginemodels.aetd(bleed='ON')
results = aetd.run(altitude=80000,mach=5,tempsls=60)
```

I'm would like to have my engine model run method send input to the 'BatchMaster' process.

My question is two parts:
1) How to do you find a multiprocessing instance in windows and send it information?
2) If there isn't an instance of that program, how do you launch it?

Thanks for any feedback or insight you can provide!

This will really help out alot of people at my workplace who aren't good at programming, and do most of their work making files via copy paste.

Comment: Are you talking about the actual [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) Python module, or just running multiple processes and having them communicate in general?

Comment: You are correct I'm using multiprocessing